# Mathematical formulation to force exponential terms in a vector to binary

Tags: exponential-function

Is it possible to express a non-negative number/function $\alpha$ mathematically, if we wanted vector: $[\exp(-\alpha|A_1-B|^2),\exp(-\alpha|A_2-B|^2),\exp(-\alpha|A_3-B|^2),...,\exp(-\alpha|A_n-B|^2)]$ to achieve $[0,1,0,...,0]$ where $\exp(-\alpha|A_2-B|^2) \rightarrow 1$ because $|A_2-B|$ is the smallest out of all the squared differences?

Edit: B are all equal

Comment: What would it produce in the event that two terms were equal and the third was larger?

Comment: They would both be 1

Comment: Because $e^{u}$ is never zero, there's no value of $\alpha$ that will do what you ask. You probably need to think about your goals a little longer and express them as clearly as possible in a new question.

Comment: Yes exp(u) is never zero, but I am looking for alpha (if it exists) that allows the limit to 0. The answer may indeed be "there is no such alpha" but I would like to know why in that case.

Comment: "allows the limit to be zero": There is no limit in your question.